# Sometimes StaleStateException in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I want to do retry whenever StaleStateException occurs, which is occurring intermittently for a query.list("select --") operation.
I don't mind losing the current session state since I'm retrying from the beginning itself.

What I currently have done is to retry whenever the exception occurs without clearing or creating a new session, which has not solved my problem.The session is obtained from HibernateDaoSupport which returns the session created at the start of the request using the interceptor.

I wanted to know which of the approach should I go with in case of retrying or Is there a better way to do?

```
private List executeMethod(String query,int count) throws Exception{
        Session session = null;
        Query queryObject = null;
        try{

            session = this.getSession();
            return session.createQuery(query).list();


        }catch(StaleStateException e){
                LOG.error("StaleStateException occured but we are doing ",e);

        //approach 1
        session.evict(objectquerried);

        //approach 2
        session.clear();

        throw e;

        }catch(HibernateException e){
            throw e;
        }finally{
          session.close();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: After some trials I realize, It's better to fail than to handle StaleStateException.